# how to enable mysql to using index for my table

Tags: mysql, explain

```
CREATE TABLE `sqq_merchant`.`other_coupon_order` (
`id`  int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`tenant_id`  varchar(32) NOT NULL ,
`store_id`  varchar(64) NOT NULL ,
`order_no`  varchar(64) NOT NULL ,
`out_order_no`  varchar(64) NOT NULL ,
`total_fee`  integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`other_coupon_fee`  integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`act_total_fee`  integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`pay_method`  tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`trade_time`  datetime NOT NULL ,
`create_time`  datetime NOT NULL ,
`update_time`  datetime NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `tenant_store_id` (`tenant_id`, `store_id`) USING BTREE ,
UNIQUE INDEX `order_no` (`order_no`) USING BTREE 
);
```

and I wanna query the order for defined tenant, defined store and defined trade time range, for example:

```
select * from other_coupon_order where tenant_id = '9001' and store_id = '1151610006' and 
trade_time > '2018-01-08 00:00:00' AND trade_time < '2018-01-08 23:59:59'
```

while I use explain for this sql, I find the type is All, the performance is bad, how can I improve the sql

this is the sql performance picture for explain

[image]

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table? Mysql makes the use of index if it find that using index is cheaper than scanning the table without using index. You can add `trade_time` to your composite index `tenant_store_id` in the same order as the columns occur in the where clause, but the index will be used if it makes sense to mysql to use the index

Comment: yes, that's helpful, thank you

Comment: @money - The order in the `WHERE` clause does not matter.  What matters is putting the `=` columns first, optionally ending with one "range" column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could  try adding  also the trade_time to the composite index  as  `(tenant_id, store_id, trade_time)`

```
 INDEX my_indx_name  (tenant_id, store_id, trade_time)
```